# Farlie-Gumbel-Morgenstern copula

Tags: correlation, gamma-distribution, copula, spearman-rho, inverse-gamma-distribution

I have the Farlie-Gumbel-Morgenstern copula and I want to generate two gamma marginals and find an expression for the linear correlation. I understand that to get the random variates $(u,v)$ I need to do the following:

Generate two independent uniform $(0; 1)$ variates u; t;

(1) $a = \theta(1 - 2u) - 1$
(2) $b = \sqrt{a^2 - 4(a + 1)t }$

(3) Set $v = 2t/(b - a)$ which gives $u$ and $v$.

So if I have 2 gamma distributions, say $\text{Gamma}(a_1,b_1)$ and $\text{Gamma} (a_2,b_2)$ I can use the $u$ and $v$ random variates that are now dependent to get back the desired gamma values but how do I find an expression for the linear coefficient? I know that the Spearman's $\rho$ is $\theta/3$ but how do I go about getting the linear coefficient (the standard one)?

Comment: Are you able to compute the expectation of the product of your two gamma variates?

Comment: Umm Im guessing that's to do with understanding the  Farlie-Gumbel-Morgenstern copula which im not sure how to. I mean I know how to apply it but getting the correlation out of it is :/

Comment: So, for example. Lets say I have 2 gamma distributions,  one is  Gamma(2.5,600) while another is Gamma (4.3, 280), so completely different, and I am using the Farlie-Gumbel-Morgenstern copula then is there a way express the linear correlation as a function of theta only?

Comment: It appears to be covered in [this arXiv paper](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1501/1501.05356.pdf)

Comment: I've been reading it, and the other papers it references, and although I understand the main concepts it seems the cases they research are only for when the Gamma distributions have a scale parameter of 1, or if the scale parameters are equal. I will keep searching but I was wondering if you knew whether there exists a formula for linear correlation for the case, like in this question, where the scale parameters are different, i.e. b1=/=b2.

Comment: To clarify the question:  given $X \sim Gamma(a,b)$, and $Y \sim Gamma(\alpha, \beta)$, you wish to construct a bivariate distribution $h(x,y)$ from these marginals, using a Morgenstern copula. Is that correct?You then wish to find the correlation between $X$ and $Y$, given their joint pdf $h(x,y)$ -- is that what you are seeking?